# File.Copy is giving exception

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, impersonation

I am using `File.Copy` to copy the file from my local system to REMOTE Server using below code.
But its giving me error:

> Either a required impersonation level was not provided, or the provided impersonation level is invalid.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
WindowsIdentity idnt = new WindowsIdentity("username", "password");
WindowsImpersonationContext context = idnt.Impersonate();
File.Copy("LocalFilepath", Path.Combine(@"\\servername\\c\\Folder1\\EmpDetails.xml"), true);
```

Thanks Gaby , i have tried the platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/… but now i am getting Exception in copying file saying that -Could not find file "LocalFile" - I have admin rights on Remote Server also.

Comment: `WindowsIdentity(string, string)` constructor does not take in username and password. It takes in username and type.

Comment: Also check out: [Impersonate with username and password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710538/impersonate-with-username-and-password)

Comment: http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Comment: Thanks Gaby , i have tried the http://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/  but now i am getting Exception in copying file saying that -Could not find file LocalFile.