# How to prompt a user for credentials and obtain its WindowsIdentity?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-identity

How can I prompt a user for credentials and obtain its `WindowsIdentity` (or something like it)?

I assume I need to use `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` from `Credui.dll` but I found this wrapper in C#: [CredentialUI](https://gist.github.com/mayuki/339952) that only uses username and password while I need to support any method available (username/password, smart card, bio-metric and etc.)

I'm pretty sure that it can be done, because of the following:

> The `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` function creates and displays a configurable dialog box that allows users to supply credential information by using any credential provider installed on the local computer.

From [CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375178(v=vs.85).aspx).

So should I use `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials` or not? If not, then what else? if I should, How?

EDIT:

This is not a duplicate of [Impersonate with username and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710538/impersonate-with-username-and-password), because my question regards to any method of authentication, especially not username/password based authentication, whereas the other question explicitly refers to username/password authentication only.